# Grouping in views

Tags: 7, views

I am very new to drupal and its module VIEWS. So I am learning drupal 7.

I want your help to understand below code(My guess is it is created with views by looking at its class):

[image]

What I have got so far is, they have created one block from the view.

**Problem** is I am not able to figure next 3 `<div>`. I guess It is created with the views Grouping.But when I try to create same thing with grouping, It is giving me unexpected result like `content:Body` goes in to the **Views Header** and other part in content.So basically all things get messed up.

Can any one please guide me ?

Comment: to understand views theming just go to advanced section  theming information from their you can get which tpl is being called for which part.

Comment: I know that but what I want to know is how that grouping is done ? I know there is one template file in views for grouping but I don't know how exactly I can make replica of above code. Can you help me please ?

Comment: on your view page their a  section called format settings click on settings and it will give you an option of grouping fields..

Comment: I have done exactly the same and mentioned in question as well.But it is giving unexpected result(May be I am doing wrongly). Can you tell me how grouping can be done if I have three `content : body` ?

Comment: if you want to group 3 fields under one html element here's the trick that will work for you :
step 1.add your fields exclude them from display.
step 2.add global custom text field in the input area write for title eg.<div>[title]</div>[title]-> you can get this under available variables option. remember to check off all checkboxes to add your own html under style ouput section.

Comment: @Twix:Could you please share the screenshot of the view set up?